# Deactivate a user who is no longer default owner of records created by guest users but still erroring?

Tags: customer-community, user-management, guest-user, experience-builder-page, deactivate

*Error: This user is the default owner of records created by guest users and can’t be deactivated.*

I keep seeing this message when I try to deactivate a user. I followed instructions given here: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000352970&type=1

I followed them, and changed the default owner in all the experience/community workspaces. I also went to the sites (sites & domains) but couldn't see the default record owner from those steps. I would assume once it's changed on the workspace, it should be sufficient, but I cannot deactivate this user without continually facing the same error.

Some first thoughts of solving:

1. Do I need to give myself special permissions to see the default record owner on the site under sites&domains rather than workspaces?
2. Do I have to change the default record owner in the communities within sandboxes as well?
3. Is there a 3rd place in settings that's holding this user as default guest record owner?

Any advice helps.

Comment: For #2 - YES, but not to get around the error in PROD; only to get around the error in the sandbox

Answer (score 2):

For this error code, you need to check "All Sites", if there are sites for which you cannot access "WorkSpace", that means you are not a member of the site, and need to be added as a member, and then you can update the default record owner. You will need to add your profile as the 'parentID" and the site ID in the "networkID". Please see this link:

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.faq_communities_membership_update_api.htm&type=5

Answer (score 1):

I found out that I had two more sites only visibles switching to Salesforce classic. Get into the classic setup and search for sites, then check there the default owner of the records and choose an active one.